# Using libcurl without installing it

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

How can I use libcurl with my project without actually installing it or curl on the system?

I want to make my source-code portable, so that any developer can copy the folder with all sources and other files, run `make` and compile the program without the need for system level installations.

I am looking for (probably separate)  solutions for Linux and for Windows (dll?). If it is possible, provide some standard/official solution and not hack (I'd like to be educated about linking third party libraries)

Comment: you can link static this library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used it on Windows using Visual Studio, all you need to do under Windows:

- Download the source
- Using CMake generate the project files (when using Visual Studio).
- Build the libraries, 3 files will be built: libcurl.lib, libcurl_imp.lib and libcurl.dll
- Include curl.h in your project and add the paths to your .lib files
- Build your program, put libcurl.dll in the executable folder and it will work.

On Linux it should be a similar process, build the libraries and include them with your source.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to build a static library out of libcurl and link agains it. Should be pretty straightforward and the process is almost identical on every OS.